# Laravel Add Post Route to Resource Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 app that is using Resource routes. I have one as follows:

```
Route::resource('submissions', 'SubmissionsController');
```

I want to add a new Post route to it for a sorting form on my index page.

```
Route::post('submissions', [
    'as' => 'submissions.index',
    'uses' => 'SubmissionsController@index'
]);
```

I have placed the Post route above my Resource route in my routes.php.

However, a validation Request named `SubmissionRequest` that is meant for forms within the Submission Resource is being executed on my new Post route. Here is my `SubmissionsController` Method.

```
public function index(SortRequest $req)
{
    $submission = new Submission;
    $submission = $submission->join('mcd_forms', 'mcd_forms.submission_id', '=', 'submissions.id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

    $data['sort_types'] = [
        'name' => 'Name',
        'form_type' => 'Type'
    ];

    $data['direction'] = ( !empty($req['asc']) ? 'asc' : 'desc' );
    $data['dataVal'] = ( !empty($req['sort_type']) ? $req['sort_type'] : 'submissions.id' );

    $submission->whereNull('submissions.deleted_at')->orderBy(
        $data['dataVal'],
        $data['direction']
    );

    $data['submissions'] = $submission->get();

    return view('submissions.index')->with($data);
}
```

So, when submitting the sorting form from my index page, it is running the SubmissionRequest validation even though I am specifically calling the SortRequest validation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are conflicting the name of the route, the `Route::resource` is already setting the route name "submissions.index" to the GET resource to the index of the controller. You should set a different name in your custom POST route. If you have any doubts of what name is assigned to which resource, remember you can always do `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I changed the name of the route to "submissions.sort" and am still running into the same issue. I understand that the resource route is adding a get method for index, but I need to add an additional post method.

I see in the documentation "Route::match()" but would using this override the resource route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it.

Since my `Post` route was conflicting with my `Get` route for `submissions.index` I added **below** the `Resource` route the following:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'submissions', [
    'as' => 'submissions.index',
    'uses' => 'SubmissionsController@index'
]);
```

This allows the route to accept both `Get` and `Post` requests by overriding the automatically generated one.

The documentation is here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#basic-routing

Comment: Wouldn't this need to come *below* the resource route to override, not above?

Comment: Yes, I confused myself and edited the response. I just returned it to its original.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'submissions', [
    'as' => 'submissions.index',
    'uses' => 'SubmissionsController@index'
]);
```

in laravel 5 its conflict with @store action